# php, jquery only first id working normal

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code in .php (code is edited for easier understanding).

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($biznis)){
<div id='listItem'>
    <div id='listPic'>
        <img src='../../social/images/avatar/empty_avatar_full.jpg'></img>
    </div>
    <div id='listCont'>
        <span>abcde<i>(request pending)</i></span>                              
    </div>
    <div id="listInfo">
        <span id='info'>More info</span>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>

    <div id='moreInfo'>
        <span>Invitation sent: xx-yy-zzzz</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div style='clear:both;'></div>
}
```

So the code is nothing special, I just get all records from the table lined up.
So now, here is the problem, as you can see, I use the same ids for the same elements.

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#moreInfo").hide();

    $("#info").click(function(){
    $("#moreInfo").slideToggle();
});
});
```

OK so here are now the problems. Only first div (#moreinfo) is hidden, all the others are shown. And only first span (#info) is toggling the slider.

I tried with putting the counter for ids, and jquery each function, but nothing realy worked as i imagined.

Ty, Sebastian

Comment: It sounds like you've identified the problem (multiple elements with the same `id`). What exactly was wrong with the solution you were trying to use? You might consider using classes instead.

Comment: you can't have duplicate ids. Use a class selector instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element IDs should be *unique* identifiers for that element. Use **classnames** for generic selectors:

```
<? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($biznis)): ?>
<div class="listItem">
    <div class="listPic">
        <img src="../../social/images/avatar/empty_avatar_full.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="listCont">
        <span>abcde<i>(request pending)</i></span>                              
    </div>
    <div class="listInfo">
        <span class="info">More info</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="moreInfo">
        <span>Invitation sent: xx-yy-zzzz</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<? endwhile; ?>
```

And change your jQuery to:

```
$(function() {
   $('.moreInfo').hide();
   $('.info').click(function() {
      $('.moreInfo').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

**Edit**

```
$('.info').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings('.moreInfo').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Ty :) Working Ok now, just one little problem left. As I click on the more info (span), all the "listItem"-s slides down, any tip, or quick solution? :)

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on info? Do you want the nearest `moreInfo` to show?

Answer (score 3):

use class and not ids because you're in a while loop. An id exists only once.

And update your JS.